# Installing jri from rJava using cygwin causes error

Tags: java, r, cygwin, jri

I am having some difficulties installing jri  using cygwin in Windows 7 64 bit
I have set R_HOME to "C:\Program Files\R\R-2.14.0"
I have also set PATH to "C:\cygwin\home\USER\rJava\jri\;C:\Program Files\R\R-2.14.0\bin\"

and I get the following error:

```
$ sh configure.win
Generate Windows-specific files (src/jvm-w32) ...
make: Entering directory `/home/USER/rJava/jri/src/win32'
Makefile:4: C:\Program: No such file or directory
Makefile:4: Files\R\R-2.14.0/etc/Makeconf: No such file or directory
make: C:Program: Command not found
make: *** No rule to make target `Files\R\R-2.14.0/etc/Makeconf'.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory `/home/USER/rJava/jri/src/win32'
```

I am running the command sh configure.win from the "C:\cygwin\home\USER\rJava\jri" directory.
 Any ideas what am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: Paths must be quoted if they contain spaces.

Comment: i have changed that, but I still get the exact same error

Comment: Try specifying the path via its short name (found by `dir /x` from the `cmd.exe` command line).  For example: `C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-2.14.0`.

Comment: I dont see the shortcut for Program Files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think we support cygwin. Please use the Rtools from http://www.murdoch-sutherland.com/Rtools/

Answer (score 1):

C:\souravmay_das\code\jni\R\R\etc\i386 contain the makeconf file move that to the parent folder (In my case it is->C:\souravmay_das\code\jni\R\R\etc)this way i was able to get it working till this level, however i got struck in the next level when i tried to execute make command.

when i execute make command i get the following error :

C:***\code\jni\JRI>make
make -C src JRI.jar
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/souravmay_das/code/jni/JRI/src'
gcc  -c -o Rengine.o Rengine.c -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -DWin32 -D_JNI
_IMPLEMENTATION_  -IC:/souravmay_das/code/jdk632/include -IC:/souravmay_das/code/jdk632/in
clude/win32 -IC:/souravmay_das/code/jni/R/R/include
Rengine.c:1: error: bad value (core2) for -mtune= switch
make[1]: *** [Rengine.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory`/c/*/code/jni/JRI/src'
make: * [src/JRI.jar] Error 2

Problem was because of this mtune flag which u can remove and try.
-mtune=core2

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should check out you make file, and make sure there are quotes around paths with spaces in it, like `C:\Program Files\R\R-2.14.0\etc\Makeconf`. Also, Since `C:\Program Files\R\2-2.14.0` is probably loaded from the `R_HOME` and `PATH` environment variable, you should look for those as well and place quotes around the paths built from them.

Comment: I did that but that doesnt seem to be the problem. I get the same error

Comment: how can i check out the make file?